# How to get those features in Netplan with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

So apparently Ubuntu 18.04  (or perhaps even one of the 17.x versions) introduced a new mechanism to configure the network interfaces called [netplan.io](https://netplan.io) or `netplan` for short.

Now all of this seems very nice at first glance, until you figure out that your configuration of the very customizable `/etc/network/interfaces` cannot be easily mapped. I guess *there's our reason for why `netplan` has no renderer for `/etc/network/interfaces`*.

The main purpose behind `netplan` appears to be to provide a unified method to express network configuration and render it in a format understandable by NetworkManager and Systemd-networkd at the time of this writing. Apparently `/etc/network/interfaces` was an afterthought (if at all). I hadn't noticed the switch first, because upgraded systems retain the old mechanism which is implemented in the package `ifupdown` (and a number of similar packages providing alternatives).

`/etc/network/interfaces` allowed one to introduce new types of stanzas by placing shell scripts in the right folders (see [here](http://www.wertarbyte.de/debian/ifupdown/addresses) for an example). This mechanism was (or in upstream Debian *is*) very powerful, but seems to be missing from `netplan`. Now `netplan` caters the functionality of the `addresses` stanza introduced by above linked script, but any other custom scripting seems to be right out (I have some scripts to bring up and attach a number of bridges for virtual machines and containers and apply firewall rules pertaining to them).

How can I achieve something similar in `netplan`? Or more generally how to get the flexibility of `/etc/network/if-{down,post-down,pre-up,up}.d` and the respective stanzas from [`interfaces(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html) (`down`, `post-down`, `pre-up`, `up`) with `netplan`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `netplan` doesn't support the `ifupdown` hook scripts , the `networkd-dispatcher`  can be used to configure your scripts.

[Netplan : Use pre-up, post-up, etc. hook scripts](https://netplan.io/faq#use-pre-up-post-up-etc-hook-scripts)

> Users of ifupdown may be familiar with using hook scripts (e.g pre-up, post-up, etc.) in their interfaces file. Netplan configuration does not currently support hook scripts in its configuration definition.
>
> Instead to achieve this functionality with the netword renderer users can use `networkd-dispatcher`.